# Redirecting URL to www.localhost/proj/ in Codeigniter after datamapper installation

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper

Hi in my project am facing redirection issue when after I placed 
`require_once APPPATH.'third_party/datamapper/bootstrap.php';` line in index.php  right before `require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';` Line. I traced both the files and come to know the issue at `call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));` line. So can any one help me out please. I've been doing this past 2 days.

Comment: do not add your php file at index.php.try to include it at your controller

Comment: Sorry did'nt get clearly..If you are talking about this line "require_once APPPATH.'third_party/datamapper/bootstrap.php" ,It is recommended by the datamapper installation

Comment: Yes I mean require_once APPPATH.'third_party/datamapper/bootstrap.php.Try to include it at your controller.From the error it seems it is try to use codeigniter controller instance and CI_URI class. Those function and class available after require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php'; So you need to include your file after that line.Best is to include it controller.

Comment: If I remove the line from line immediately rendering error as ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::dm_call_method() in I:\wamp\www\proj\application\libraries\datamapper.php on line 1113

Comment: This is another problem.It seems it is trying to connect database and failed.Are you using this ?http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/. if so please look at their installation process http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/installation.html

Comment: I did the same exactly like link above.

Comment: I remove my code from index and added in controller.Still CI_DB_mysqli_driver::dm_call_method() error persist